# Determine if Unity Remote is being used?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

Is there a way to check if Unity Remote is being used in the editor? [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/166277/how-to-detect-unity-remote.html) doesn't seem to be working with Unity Remote 5?

Comment: Which version of unity are you using ? The code in the link that you referenced is fine BTW I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2 and Unity Remote 5

Comment: Mind sharing some code? Maybe it´s something else

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti I am using Unity 2019.1.2f1

Comment: Are you able to play the game from the Unity remote i.e from your android device when its connected?

Comment: @JoseAntonioNavarroMarco I just figured out where I was going wrong and I've submitted an answer. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti Yes it does work, but no worries, I've just figured out where I was going wrong and I've submitted an answer. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `UnityRemote` has a small delay before running your application, and `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isRemoteConnected` is only true once it has detected that your application is successfully running on your device.

Initially I was checking whether a handheld device was connected in the `Awake` function, but because my application had not yet successfully started running on my device yet, it displayed as false.

The fix was therefore to instead test for this in the `Update` function.